# Visual Studio 2017 wont show c++ template/extansion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

I am trying to use Microsoft visual studio IDE to run my c++ code, however, when I go to create a project, I do not see the option for a c++ project. I tried reinstalling the program to see if I could somehow install the package/extension however it just won't seem to come up.

The only templates that appear are in c# or f#. 
If someone could please lead me into the right direction so that I can fix this, it would be great. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You must enable it in the installer

Comment: Is this Visual Code or Visual Studio ? Looks like VC on the image.

Comment: this is visual studio, not visual code. It is the newest version on mac

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of C++ in the [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes).

According to [this post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef99e9f5-2a48-423b-b6c0-fa5617d7c63d/how-do-i-get-c-to-work-on-visual-studio-for-mac?forum=visualstudiogeneral), there is no C++ support in the Mac version of Visual Studio. It contains links to instructions for using Visual Studio Code, as well as the option to install a VM running Windows.

Apparently Visual Studio Code supports C++ projects, since it can execute external tools. The Microsoft Visual C++ build tools are [free for Windows](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), but I don't think there is a version for the Mac, so some other external compiler is necessary.